# Adding variables to a list in CLisp

Tags: list, variables, append, lisp, addition

I want to take variables I've created and add their values to a list. For example

```
(setq num1 34)
(setq num2 49)
(setq num3 30)
(setq num_list '(num1 num2 num3))
```

But this returns the literal strings I put in the list (num1, num2, num3) not their values (34,49,30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list`:

```
[1]> (setq num1 34)
34
[2]> (setq num2 49)
49
[3]> (setq num3 30)
30
[4]> (setq num-list (list num1 num2 num3))
(34 49 30)
```

(Also, note that you should usually declare variables with `defparameter` or `defvar`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use backquote and unquote to achieve this:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2))
  `(,a ,b))
```